Does "To the Moon" generate interest while using the Green Deck?
The description of the Green Deck says:

At end of each Round:
$2 per remaining Hand
$1 per remaining Discard
Earn no Interest

The the description for the Joker “To the Moon” says:

Earn an extra $1 of interest for every $5 you have at end of round

Will To the Moon generate interest if you are using the Green Deck?

No. Having To the Moon will not generate Interest while you are using the Green Deck.
Source: I bought To The Moon while using the Green Deck and did not receive Interest at the end of the round.

